# visual studio 2008 CSS upgrading

Tags: .net, css, upgrade

Is there any way to upgrade the CSS version of visual studio 2008.
It is currently using CSS 2.1. I want to use CSS3.
Please share your thoughts.

Comment: You can use CSS3 in VS2008...Unless you want - **[CSS3 intellisense](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikhailarkhipov/archive/2007/10/19/how-to-create-custom-css-intellisense-schema-in-visual-studio-2005-and-2008.aspx)** or **[CSS 3 Intellisense Schema](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210)**

Comment: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210

Comment: @NickR Yeah. I want to have css3 intellisense in vs2008. The link you provided is for vs2010.

Answer (score 0):

1. download and run the installer from the link . http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210?SRC=Home
2. Open registry edit. Run-regedit
3. 2a. Find: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Packages{A764E895-518D-11d2-9A89-00C04F79EFC3}\Schemas

   ```
     2b. From there add a Key: Schema 5

     2c. Add two string values

               Keyname: File
               Value: css30.xml

               Keyname: Friendly Name
               Value: CSS 3.0
   ```
4. Make sure css30.xml is located in C:\program files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\common7\packages\1033\schemas\css

5.In there you will find css.xsd, css10,css20,css21, and css-ie60. If you don't find CSS30.xml in this folder use windows search and copy the css30.xml file into this folder

6.Restart VS and open any given CSS file. Select CSS 3.0 and it should have CSS 3.0 validation enabled.
It works in vs2010.try in vs2008

Comment: After doing the steps that you mentioned, I can see 'CSS 3' option in the dropdown list along with css2,2.1 etc in my stylesheet file in vs2008. But I can't select or use it..

Comment: Does this require vs2008 service pack1?